# FTP webrequest in c#

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

can any one explain , In FTP GetResponse() method by using MKD , how to create directory name having symbol (#) . it is not working .

Comment: MKD   represent the property  to make directory   in ftprequest .

e.g.  reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;

suppose if you want to make directory e.g. RITCH#ME   .
then by that code it is truncating directory name to "RITCH"

Answer (score 0):

You should try an urlencode your directory string before I am just guessing have not tested this

```
string directory = HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode("RITCH#ME");
```

Comment: i am developing it on windows application using c# .  "HttpServerUtility" is used under system.Web.

Comment: i am developing it on windows application using c# . "HttpServerUtility" is used under system.Web.                                            complete code is                                                 FtpWebRequest reqFTP1;
reqFTP1 = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://ftpservername/RITCH#ME"));      
 reqFTP1.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID,ftpPassword);
 reqFTP1.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
 reqFTP1.UseBinary = true;                 
 FtpWebResponse response1 = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP1.GetResponse();

Comment: replace # with %23

new Uri("ftpservername/RITCH%23ME";))